# Generating random matrix in c

Tags: c, matrix, row

so I got program with finds max value from each row in matrix, now how can I generate random matrix with, for example: n length and m height?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void max_per_row( double *result, 
                      double matrix[][3], 
                      const int xmax, 
                      const int ymax)
{
int x=0, y=0;

 for(y=0; y < ymax; y++)
    result[y]=y;
for(y=0; y < ymax; y++)
{
    for(x=0; x < xmax; x++)
    {
        if ( matrix[y][x] > result[y] )
            result[y]=matrix[y][x];
    }
}
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
double test1[3][3]={ {-10, -20, 0},
                     {-13, 0,  13},
                     {-99, 99.99, 100.01}};
double result[10]={0};
int y=0;
max_per_row(result, test1, 3, 3 );
for(y=0; y < 3 ; y++)
    printf("max row %d = %f\n", y, result[y]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: what part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Use the [`rand()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rand.html) function (and [`srand()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/srand.html)) declared in `<stdlib.h>`. You'll probably also want the [`time()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rand.html) function, declared in `<time.h>`. Have fun.

Comment: Randomly sized? (ie random `n` and `m` values) or filed with random data?

Comment: @Mike just filled with random numbers.

Comment: @TJD  I want to input how many rows and how many columns matrix will have and also fill matrix with random numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    int random[3][3];
    int i, o;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(o = 0; o<3; o++)
        for(i = 0; i<3; i++)
            random[o][i] = rand();
    return 0;
}
```

That'll do it. If you want a particular subset of data you can use the `%` operator on the output from `rand()`, for example:

```
rand() % 10; // generates a random number 0-9
```

Comment: @downvoter - An issue with this answer?