# How to avoid SIGSEV Segmentation fault in C when allocating random elements to an int 2D matrix in a function?

Tags: c, matrix, linear-algebra, segmentation-fault

I am doing an assignment where we are required to assign random integers to a 5x5 matrix using array notation (so cannot use pointers here). After looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589248/generating-random-matrix-in-c) closed Stack Overflow non-question, I wrote the following newbie code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

#define rows 5
#define cols 5

void fillMatrix(int matrix[rows][cols])
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
        for(int j = 0; i<cols; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 100 + 1;
}

int main()
{
    int matrix[rows][cols];
    fillMatrix(matrix);
}
```

The SIGSEGV Segmentation error happens in the line

```
 matrix[i][j] = rand() % 100 + 1;
```

according to `gdb`.  Also, using `backtrace` I was able to see that this error arises from here:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0 0x0000000000400690 in fillMatrix (matrix=0x7fffffffe7d0) at program.c:13
#1 0x00000000004006d2 in main () at program.c:19
```

My understanding is that the values being allocated are addressing memory locations which are not defined within the matrix, or are simply not allowed to be accessed. So considering `backtrace`, does this mean that the way I am declaring the matrix in the main function is wrong? Or is my function `fillMatrix()` itself wrong at the line in question?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug. Change "i" to "j" in your code.

```
void fillMatrix(int matrix[rows][cols])
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
        for(int j = 0; i<cols; j++)     << here is a bug
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 100 + 1;
}
```

Comment: The question should just be closed as a typo, it's not worth posting full-blown answers to simple mistakes like this. It can be answered in a comment.